# How to round exact double value using Math.Round

Tags: c#, double

I want to round the double value exactly currently it giving me like...

```
val = 0.01618

Math.Round(val,2)
```

`0.02` (currently it's giving like this).

`0.01` (I want like this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Math.Floor to get it to your prefered value and then use Math.Round to get it to 2 decimals, like this:

```
// Returns double that is rounded and floored
double GetRoundedFloorNumber(double number, int rounding)
{
    return ((Math.Floor(number * (Math.Pow(10, rounding))) / Math.Pow(10, rounding)));

}
```

So calling this function should return the right number:

Example code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Writes 0.016 to the screen
        Console.WriteLine(GetRoundedFloorNumber(0.01618, 3));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static double GetRoundedFloorNumber(double number, int rounding)
    {
        return ((Math.Floor(number * (Math.Pow(10, rounding))) / Math.Pow(10, rounding)));

    }
```

Comment: Hmm its not working when i gave rounding as 3 still i'm getting 0.01 only after gave rounding as 3 but it should display 0.016

Comment: Are you sure you did everything right? I pasted the code (added one extra ')' though) in visual studio and everythings works just fine.

Comment: yes i did every thing but it giving me same two digits like 0.01

Comment: I rechecked the code and everything still works just like it should. I'll re-edit the answer with a complete code listing of a simple console program that does what you want in case that helps you out.

Answer (score 3):

`Math.Floor()` is what you're looking for, I think. If you want to round to the two decimal signs, you could do `Math.Floor(v*100)/100`. I wonder why there's no overload of `Floor` that takes the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is Math.Floor() or something similar (don't no c#, sorry). This would always round down. Math.Round() does it like described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

Answer (score 0):

This will round down where you wanted it;

```
Math.Round(val - 0.005, 2)
```